# Iterate over line edit widgets in order

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a piece of code that iterates over LineEdit widgets to build a string. The problem that I having is that it seems to iterate randomly making parsing the string very difficult.

```
for widget in qApp.allWidgets():
    if isinstance(widget, QLineEdit):
       insertQuery += widget.displayText()
```

Comment: How do you expect to define proper order? Using positioning or tab order or something else?

Comment: I never thought about tab order. Basically anything that would allow me to control the order. Or at least know what order to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution thanks to @mFoxRU

First I set objectName in the loop to create the line edit objects

```
LineEdit.setObjectName(str(i))
```

Then I use FocusOut to set value of line edit objects to a dictionary

```
LEDict = {'1': '', '2': '', '3': '', '4': '', '5': '', '6': '', '7': '', '8': '', '9': '', '10': '', '11': '', '12': ''}
if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            LEDict[widget.objectName()] = widget.displayText()
            return False
```

Finally, I iterate over the dictionary using range which I can use to construct the sql statement

```
for i in range(12):
            x = i + 1
            print(LEDict[str(x)])
```

Actually, I have eliminated the for loop in favor of a single statement that calls the dictionary elements directly to construct the sql code.

```
testInsert = "Insert INTO address VALUES(" + LEDict["1"] + ", " + LEDict["2"] + ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

`allWidgets()` does not guarantee any particular order. There are couple of ways to achieve your goal.

- You may manually create a list of widgets and iterate over it.
- You can specify tab order and use `nextInFocusChain()` to move to the next item on order.
- Add some property with order number and collect text values to `dict` with order number as key, and join values afterwards.
- Similarly to previous variant, you may use some naming convention for `QLineEdit` like adding order number to widget's `objectName`

Which way you will choose is up to you and depends on how you are creating UI.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying create a form that uses a save button to push the values of the of the line edits into a database. Guaranteeing the initial focus would be very hard but I could force initial focus but then I have to worry about creating an infinite loop that keeps moving focus.

Comment: And see the LineEdits are created with a loop that reuses the same variable.

Comment: I don't see anything that allows me to set objectName for Line Edit objects.

Comment: Well, if you create them in a loop, you can just add them to a list and iterate on it later. Seems like an easiest solution.